# Style Guide: Bold, Italic, or Quotes When I Want to Emphasize Something

Tags: writing, writing-style

Let’s say I have many lists of this kind on a page:

1. Click on the Foo button.
2. Tick the Bar box.
3. Click on the Save button.

How should I emphasize *Foo*, *Bar*, and *Save*?

1. Bold?

   1. Click on the **Foo** button.
   2. Tick the **Bar** box.
   3. Click on the **Save** button.
2. Italic?

   1. Click on the *Foo* button.
   2. Tick the *Bar* box.
   3. Click on the *Save* button.
3. Quotes?

   1. Click on the “Foo” button.
   2. Tick the “Bar” box.
   3. Click on the “Save” button.

NOTE: I want the lists to be read as easy as possible.

Comment: This is really a matter of preference. Most of the UI stuff I've created, especially directions for web applications, use quotes.

Comment: I like to use quotes. Bold is much easier to scan and read. I can’t decide!

Comment: "Click on the `Foo` button." is how it's done conventionally.

Comment: You should **never** use quotes to _emphasise_ something. In this case, though, you're not really emphasising as such—you're quoting literally a string of text that appears on the button/link/menu entry/what-have-you. So quotes work here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is purely a matter of style, which is entirely subjective.

When writing this sort of text, I tend to use bold for button names, but there may be the means to name the actual button itself: <kbd>foo</kbd>

Using such styling might be useful if your line spacing is sufficiently wide to accommodate it.

Comment: That looks great on the page, as well.

Answer (score 0):

"Click on the `Foo` button." is how it's done conventionally.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I use:

- **Bold:** use for sudden contrast, when the emphasis shouldn't be fleeting and need to refer later, or when the emotion is pushed to extreme
- **Italic:** use when the word naturally emerge and dissipate into the flow
- **Underline:** sentence breakdown, because it can differentiate a segment with multiple words, and multiple segment close together
- **Quote:** wording choice, which can be a new term just being coined, or a sarcasm